# Using msal for python in a mobile app developed in python and Kivy. Is there any way to open the browser in app itself in Interactive flow

Tags: python, kivy, azure-ad-msal

We are developing a simple mobileapp using Python and Kivy. We are using microsoft-authentication-library-for-python for authentication using Azure AD B2C.

Tried out below one and authentication is working fine.
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/interactive_sample.py

But for authentication, right now its opening a browser outside the mobile app. Is there any way to open the browser inside the mobile app itself.